# document.write to display content on same page.

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt with javascript document.write method. Mostly when I use document.write() it shows me the content written with the method in a different page. For instance, if I write the command like this, document.write("Hello, My name is Sameeksha"); then the execution of this line takes me to a different document on the same page. I want to be able to append the message on the same page, with other elements of the page. For example, if I have text boxes and buttons on the page and I want the text with document.write to appear under all the content of the page or on a particular section of a page. Please suggest what can be done to get the output in this way? As, this way it will be really easy to create dynamic HTML content. 
   Thank you so much for your time.

Regards, 
    Sameeksha Kumari

Comment: Place a div or some html element where you want to keep the content and keep the content there

Comment: Oh God, please don't use `document.write` to change the DOM, if you do you'll be back here tomorrow asking why the document is suddenly empty!

Comment: Hi.... Thanks for the help, but it still does not work.... I tried to use <div> outside the document.write and enclosing document.write() too... But it did not work for me.

Comment: function display()
{  return "<div class = 'hiii'> hiiiiiiiiii, My name is sameeksha</div>";
 
 } here is the code I wrote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.write` is basically never used in modern Javascript.

Whan you do instead is to create explicit DOM elements and append them to the document in the place you want. For example

```
var x = document.createElement("div");  // Creates a new <div> node
x.textContent = "Hello, world";         // Sets the text content
document.body.appendChild(x);           // Adds to the document
```

Instead of appending to the end you can also add child nodes to any existing node. For example:

```
function addChatMessage(msg) {
    var chat = document.getElementById("chat"); // finds the container
    var x = document.createElement("div");
    x.textContent = msg;
    chat.appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much... It works and thanks for sharing the idea of creating the chat also... I am very new to javascript and it was a great help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say 6502 posted the more correct way to do it, but I think someone should mention `innerHTML` as well. First, give some element in your HTML body an id so you can reference it:

```
<div id="outputDiv">I'm empty.</div>
```

Then, either at the bottom of your document (at the end of the `<body>` tag), or any other time after the page is loaded, you can update the contents with `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello!!!</h1>";
```

[Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating this.](http://jsfiddle.net/WPXNb/) This isn't as clean/correct/elegant as using the more standard DOM methods, but it's well supported. Sometimes quick and dirty is what you need!

Comment: hiii... Thanks for the information, it works. But it replaces the original content. So that it does not replace original content, I used this.

Comment: var existing = document.getElementById("check").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = existing + "<h1>Hello!!!</h1>";
 Thank you so much..

Comment: @user2549994 - You could just use the `+=` operator instead: `document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML += "<h1>Hello!!!</h1>";`